# How can I secure a CVS and Web Server Network?

Tags: security, networking

As part of my computer security class, I have to design a network topology diagram and security system for a fake software design company.

It has to have an external anonymous cvs server, external web server, internal cvs and web servers, and a mail server. I'm kind of getting lost between all the different security vulnerabilities.

[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRID4.png)

Outside users are supposed to only access external servers...and internal users should be able to publish code to the external cvs server.

So my main question is: Will a dual firewall and DMZ defense work in this situation?

How does the web server fit in to this? I've heard that there should be defense from the back end of a website, like for user authentication. I'm going to be using github enterprise when I state some of my security designs and assumptions, but how does that fit in with my topology?

[Github Security](https://github.com/business/features)

Comment: Just a gratuitous comment: in 2016, CVS is totally, irrevocably, permanently deprecated. Even for a computer security class assignment, that's of absolutely no interest. I sincerely sympathize with you having to stand the classes of an utterly incompetent teacher still using the exact same material as he did 10 or more years ago, as if technology didn't evolved. What a pity. Hope you'll take the time/make the effort to go beyond what he teaches you.

Comment: Now, on the more hopefully useful side: You would better ask this on http://serverfault.com/ or http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/. You can use your http://stackoverflow.com/ account for this, linking it to these communities too. Go to the site, upper right click on "join this community".

Comment: Lol thanks for the advice,

Comment: I hope my school experience isnt that bad, but the material does seem old...=P